Power Automate Flow Not Updating Excel Table After File Upload to SharePoint
I'm struggling on how to update the row in the excel file because the flow should keep updating whenever new files are added, but it's not returning anything. Appreciate your help!



I'm trying to create a Power Automate flow that updates an Excel table (called 'Trigger List') when a raw Excel file is uploaded to one of two SharePoint folders. The table has three columns: Country, File, and Indicator. If someone uploads a file in folder1/folder2, the Indicator should be marked as 'Yes,' and if no file is uploaded, it stays blank.

The Key Value is the key on the row that you want to update.  Having YES or NO can't be used as the key, that only gives you the ability to have two rows AND you're not even updating any data, the filename (or whatever you've got in your spreadsheet) looks to be what you need to enter into the Key Value field, I'm making that assumption.  Show us your spreadsheet and then maybe I can help.
